# Shortcode as an value in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I have a button shortcode on my website which I will be using in all of my posts.
What I want is, If I modified the button value the changes should be applied to all the button on the website.So that I don't have to modify each and every post.

I want to change the buttons **Caption**, **Link** and maybe **rel**

**For example:**

```
[button rel="[btn-rel]" url="[btn-url]"] [btn-cap] [/button]
```

I googled the problem and added following code to Function.php to change the button caption.

```
function btn_cap() {  
    return 'More Freebies!';
}
add_shortcode('btn-cap', 'btn_cap');
```

and added the Shortcode to the button shortcode like this:

```
[button][btn-cap][/button]
```

Which didn't worked out :( The caption of the button is "[btn-cap]" not "More freebies"

I really want this thing to work as it will save me alot of time and work.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why not add arguments to your shortcode like [button rel="the-rel" url="the-url"][/button] and then process those parameters in your shortcode? See more on Shortcode arguments here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: As of now I only want to change the **Button title** .As I can redirect the link when ever I want.But the problem is with the Button Title.. I want to control the title of the button from the backend. PHP is new for me so don't have an idea.Can it also be done using Javascript? I don't have an idea on how to use a Shortcode inside a shortcode.

Comment: You can set a title attribute like  [button title="button-title"][/button] and then process that in your functions.php. To be honest, the answer is explained very well below and should be able to help you out here

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use shortcodes as variables/placeholders as in your example. You can however write your own button shortcode with the default values you require.

Add the following to **functions.php**

```
function freebie_button( $atts, $content = null) {
    // Default values
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'rel'   => 'nofollow',
            'url'   => '/',
            'cap'   => 'More Freebies!',
        ), $atts );

    $rel = 'rel="' . $atts['rel'] . '" ';
    // remove 'rel' attribute if it's empty
    if($rel === ''){
        $rel = '';
    }

    return '<a ' . $rel . 'href="' . $atts['url'] . '">' . $atts['cap'] . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode('freebutton', 'freebie_button');
```

**Uses**

```
[freebutton]
[freebutton rel="" url="#" cap="Buy this"]
[freebutton cap="Read "]More[/freebutton]
```

**Output**

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/">More Freebies!</a>
<a href="#">Buy this</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/">Read More</a>
```

Hopefully this code will get you started.

Comment: The code is returning a 500 server error if the function.php file is saved!

Comment: Problem is in the return  line

Comment: @Krypto is correct. It should be `return '<a...` not  `return = '<a...`. I changed my example